# "machine sleep" + WaitForSingleObject + finite timeout

Tags: winapi, mutex, waitforsingleobject

Strange question here -- but:

If I use WaitForSingleObject on a mutex with a 20 minute timeout.  Then, the machine enters sleep mode (or hibernate) while waiting....  Upon wake 12 hours later -- will my call to WaitForSingleObject time-out?  or will the timer suspend with the machine sleep?

Comment: maybe this article will help http://www.flounder.com/time.htm

Answer (score 3):

According to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687032(v=vs.85).aspx, WaitForSingleObject does take time spent in low-power states into account, but only starting from Windows 8. So on Windows 7 it should behave as described above, but on Windows 8 and later the call will time out only when the system has been actively running for the requested amount of time.

Comment: It seems you have problems with english. The MSDN says exactly the OPPOSITE: Windows 8 and 10: " The dwMilliseconds value does not include time spent in low-power states. For example, the timeout does not keep counting down while the computer is asleep."

Answer (score 1):

Just tested on Windows 7 with 5 minutes timeout and 10 minutes sleep. I was waiting for endless thread.

Surprise - `WaitForSingleObject` was timed out after my machine waked up.

Comment: No, this is not a surprise. This behaviour is exactly what the MSDN says.

Answer (score 1):

Excerpt from MSDN:

Windows XP, Windows Server 2003, Windows Vista, Windows 7, Windows Server 2008 and Windows Server 2008 R2:  The dwMilliseconds value does include time spent in low-power states. For example, the timeout **does** keep counting down while the computer is asleep.

Windows 8, Windows Server 2012, Windows 8.1, Windows Server 2012 R2, Windows 10 and Windows Server 2016:  The dwMilliseconds value **does not** include time spent in low-power states. For example, the timeout does not keep counting down while the computer is asleep.